# Angular material date picker: check invalid date for not required date field

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material date picker returns moment object and it returns null for both invalid date format as well as null/empty date field.

Is there any way to distinguish between invalid date format and empty date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular's Reactive Forms, you can include Validator methods on the Form Controls, such that they will be flagged with the respective errors.

```
yourForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  date: [null, Validators.required]
});
```

You can access the errors on the above Abstract Control by calling the errors property, as specified on the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#properties).

```
this.yourForm.controls.date.valid;
// returns true or false
```

If you want to check for a specific error, such as `required`, you may make use of the `hasError()` method

```
this.yourForm.controls.date.hasError('required');
```

Answer (score 2):

In Angular Material 8, there is formatting error distinct from the required error which only appears if you had the Validators.required validators.

With a wrong date format you get the following errors :

```
birthdate.errors = {
  "required": true,
  "matDatepickerParse": {
    "text": "44/3/2020"
  }
}
```

So to distinguish look at the error under "matDatepickerParse" key.

With an empty input you get :

```
birthdate.errors = {
  "required": true
}
```